# Monthly averages for period passed this year

Tags: mysql

I have several amounts for several days of several weeks of several
months of several years :-)-O

I can do the whole year, current Quarter, current Month and current
Week but now also want to know the (total) monthly average for all
months prior to the current one of the current year.

Ie if I had (today) a total of 600 for 2015-01-01 to 2015-06-30 I want it 
to say something like:

```
Average 2015-06-30 100
```

and if in August I had a total of 800 for 2015-01-01 to 2015-07-31 I want it to say

```
Average 2015-06-30 114.29
```

(I can do the rounding of 114.28571428571429 :-)-O)

Thanks in advance

el

Comment: I don't understand how a 6 month average is different from a 3 month one (or whatever period).

Comment: I don't think that's what he wants - I believe he wants a variable number of months, thru the last full month - so it could be 4 months, 7, 9, 11... and he doesn't want to modify the query every time he wants to run the SELECT.  OP there are many date functions here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html - you may have to use many to cobble together a SELECT .... WHERE SomeVariable BETWEEN nnnnnnnn AND mmmmmmm. I'll post an answer if I get it

Answer (score 0):

Tested (with my data since you did not supply any):

SELECT .... FROM YourTable WHERE....
SomeDateVariable BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-01-01') AND
LAST_DAY(curdate()-INTERVAL 30 DAY);

This will do your calculation for data between the 1st of the current year and the last day of the previous month - which I believe you were asking for. Please select my answer.

Comment: Thank you,

I should have written that I know how to get the previous  (indeed 
flexible) interval.  
  
I can average the payments over that interval, but I want to know 
what the monthly average was for that interval.  
  
Jan Total: 100  
Feb Total: 100  
Mar Total: 100  
  
I want to see 100.  
  
Jan Total: 100  
Feb Total: 200  
Mar Total: 300  
  
I want to see 200  
  
Jan Total: 100  
Feb Total: 200  
Mar Total: 300  
Apr Total: 400  
  
I want to see 250  
  
I  hope that makes it clearer,  (unfortunately I can't format this better)
  
el